# CakePHP and Twitter bootstrap

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.1

I saw few different solutions to implement twitter bootstrap with cakephp

My question is - what the best solution of them???

I wish to use for my app latest versions of cakephp and twitter bootstrap.

Solution that I need is to bake app and after that views must be already working with twitter bootstrap (so additional helpers for twitter bootstrap is not a good solution). What I found is:

- http://www.mtkocak.net/?p=338 - as I understand this is js libriary that will add additional classes to standart cake view or thomething like this
- https://github.com/netors/cakephp-shell-template-twitter-bootstrap - this solution seems like what I need, but I think it wouldn't work with latest versions of cake/bootstrap correctly

Can anyone who already tried to find best solution for this tell me what he/she found???

Thanx.

Comment: Have you considered using bake templates?

Answer (score 2):

I just thought that it would be useful for others who stumble upon this question thread to know that someone did put together something for the community. You'll find it here:
https://github.com/vz28bh/CakePHP-Bootstrap-Templates

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to [change the HTML of the bake templates](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html#modify-default-html-produced-by-baked-templates), and then share your templates with the community n_n

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to create forms in my views compatible with Twitter Bootstrap:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
            'div' => 'control-group',
            'label' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
            'between' => '<div class="controls">',
            'after' => '</div>',
            'class' => '',
            'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'div', 'class' => 'alert alert-error'))),
    'class' => 'form-horizontal'));
echo $this->Form->input('login');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

This is the final output:

```
<form action="path/to/action" class="form-horizontal" id="UserForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    </div>
    <div class="control-group required">
    <label for="UserLogin" class="control-label">Login</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="data[User][login]" class=""  maxlength="255" type="text" id="UserLogin">
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check it out **CakeStrap** (https://github.com/Rhym/cakeStrap)

This are the really easy steps to follow:

1) Download the .zip file

2) The files have been placed in the folders that will already be in your cakePHP app, simply follow the rabbit hole and place the folders/files in their correct locations:
 - The "Templates" folder goes in app/Console
 - The "Themed" folder goes in app/View

3) To enable your theme add public $theme = "Cakestrap"; to your "AppController" class.

4) If you would like to generate your app with the bakery then make sure you have enabled your theme before running the script.

Cheers!